# Is it mandatory to return a promise if I return to a function from another using .then operation?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to switch to another portal from one portal in the same system and then after switching I need to route in to a specific page. and the `href` for the page is `'#/xx/xx/xx/'`.

```
 $root.getData = function (xxx) {
                const con = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id'));
                if (con !== xxx.id){

                    var
                        modalInstance = commonModal.confirmation({
                            buttons: {
                                actionText: 'Yes, change it'
                            },
                            body: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                            title: 'xxx'

                        }).result.then(function success(params) {
                            if (params==='continue') {
                                return util.changeid(xxx.id).then(function success(params) {
                                   if (params === 'continue') {
                                        ($window.location.href = '#/xx/xx/xx/');
                                    }
                                })
                            }else {
                                $window.location.href = '#/xx/xx/xx/';
                            }
                        })
                } else {
                    $window.location.href = '#/xx/xx/xx/';
                }
            };
```

Here I'm using the `.then` operator to execute a function after the success of its' parent function.Do I have to pass a promise in order to use the `.then` operator since I'm using the return that I get from the parent function to execute the next function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promise is used to let the function that is listening to the function that you are sending data to , to let know that he is sending a result no matter what. and then using .then you are executing the logic that you need to execute after getting the result that was promised is returned to you

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you are returning from one function to another then is a must to use `.then` since the function that you are returning the value is expecting a result from the function that sends the value.

So, by using `promise` we are telling the function that it will get a result, no matter what.